# Derivative of a function for a given x in Maple

Tags: functions, maple

I'm stuck on something that must be incredible simple to do. I calculate the second derivative of $f(x) = e^{\sin(x)}$ like so in Maple:

```
diff(diff(exp(sin(x)),x),x);
```

But now i want to calculate $D^2f(0)$, and can't seem to find a proper way to do this...

I tried:

```
 fsolve(Deriv = 0, x);
```

with `Deriv:=diff(diff(...))` but that gives me $1,57...$ but it has to be $1$.

Comment: edit: here's the proper way to do it
f := x-> exp(sin(x)); D(D(f))(0);

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command of `fsolve(Deriv = 0, x);` actually solves the equation $D^2 f(x) = 0$ for $x$, which isn't what you want. Instead, you want to compute $D^2 f(0)$, which is simply the second derivative $D^2 f$ evaluated at $x = 0$.

Here, the second derivative $D^2 f$ is 
$$
D^2 f(x) = e^{\sin(x)} \cos^2(x) - e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x), 
$$
so plugging in $x = 0$ yields $D^2 f (0) = 1$ as you wanted.

Comment: Ok so i did: `Deriv:=diff(diff(exp(sin(x)),x),x);` and `subs(x=0,Deriv);` which gave me the correct answer. Then `evalf(%);` to make it show $1$. Thanks.